# Save image data from glReadPixels to JPEG

Tags: opengl, jpeg

I have a piece of code that uses glReadPixels to capture byte images from frame buffer (code below), now how do I save that into a jpeg file?

```
char* pdata = new char[width * height * 4]; // 4 is for RGBA
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pdata);
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest downloading [libjpeg](http://www.ijg.org/). Or any one of a number of image processing libraries. [DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/) (which hasn't been updated recently, but certainly works), [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/), etc.

Comment: The libjpeg code comes with a sample, look for the file djpeg.c